# Communicate with web services via proxy defined in WPAD

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, proxy

I'm developing a Windows WPF application that needs to communicate with certain web services. I now need to implement support for certain users that are sitting behind proxies. In one particular case, the user gets the proxy settings automatically with WPAD via Internet Explorer settings:

[image]

I have plowed through numerous articles regarding proxies but i simply can't get it to work. Here's what I've tried:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
request.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

The documentation for WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy() says:

> "Returns a proxy configured with the Internet Explorer settings of the
>   currently impersonated user."

And it seems to fetch the settings from Internet Explorer. When i debug and inspect proxy i see that it has detected the WPAD file:

[image]

But it doesn't seem to work anyway. When GetResponse() is called it fails with the following exception message:

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond"

As far as i know i shouldn't need to have anything in my app.config file. So what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proxy element in your app.config file:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true" >
        <proxy autoDetect="true" scriptLocation="http:/wpad.dat"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa91de1e(v=vs.110).aspx

Another way of doing it, though it is considered legacy is:

```
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/",true);
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
request.Proxy = proxyObject;
```

Comment: Is that really necessary? because it certainly looks like GetSystemWebProxy() found the wpad.data file?